# Find the default collation of a database from the sql file exported

Tags: mariadb

I'm working on a project where I have to find all the information about the structure of a database from the sql file exported. When working on the project I see that there's tables that set it's collation to default, meaning the collation of the database, but I couldn't find any information about the database's collation from the sql file.
 
The only collation related line in the file is this:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Is it possible to get the database's collation from this line? How does the server knows the table's collation when importing a sql file?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using mariadb

Comment: `COLLATION` (how things compare) is irrelevant; `CHARACTER SET` (the encoding) is perhaps what you meant to ask?  "utf8_general_ci" is a collation; "utf8" is the corresponding character set.

Comment: I'm asking about the collation. As you create a new database in PHPMyAdmin, you can choose from the beginning what collation you will be using for that database. I'm looking for the information about that chosen default collation of the database in the exported SQL file of that database.